# Image Successfully Downloads From Node Server But Does Not Display

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a folder on my node server called `/pictures/renamed`. In it, I'm trying to save an image and it does successfully save it however it doesn't display anything except a message that says "It appears that we don't support this file format". I changed the image extension to jpeg, jpg and png but the image still doesnt display. Why is this happening?

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser =  require('body-parser')
const app = express();
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const cors = require('cors');
const pathh  = require('path')


//Setting up the cors config
app.use(cors());

//BodyParser middleware
app.use(express.json());


function download(){
  const url = 'https://unsplash.com/photos/3aqiY4t1qxM/download?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MXxhbGx8Mnx8fHx8fDJ8fDE2NTY3Njg2Mzc&force=true'
  const path = pathh.resolve("./pictures/renamed/", 'imageWorld.jpg')
  const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(path)


https.get(url,(res)=>{

    res.pipe(fileStream)

    fileStream.on('finish',()=>{
      fileStream.close()
    })
  })



}

download();

//Serve static files if in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){

  //Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;



app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: There you are again :) what's your photo file extension ?

Comment: photo file extension is jpg as indicated in the code

Comment: Are you able to open the image by dragging it into Chrome ?

Comment: No I just see a small white square

Comment: I found that the response is an html document telling you "You are being redirected" rather than actual jpg data.
`<html><body>You are being <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656712193135-ef15d7ea27d6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;dl=georgie-cobbs-3aqiY4t1qxM-unsplash.jpg&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb">redirected</a>.</body></html>`

Comment: As a side note, in your app.get(...) handler, you have `pathh` in scope, whereas `path` results in reference error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the response is an html document (telling you that you are redirected) rather than actual jpg data. 
It looks something like this in a text editor:
`<html><body>You are being <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656712193135-ef15d7ea27d6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;dl=georgie-cobbs-3aqiY4t1qxM-unsplash.jpg&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb">redirected</a>.</body></html>`
So, what you saved was not a valid photo file.

Referring to https://github.com/follow-redirects/follow-redirects, I ran `npm install follow-redirects` then replaced `const https = require('https')` with `const { https } = require('follow-redirects')` in the js file, and then I could get the jpg.